# Scala isolate certain flatmap

Tags: scala, playframework, reactive-programming, dry

I have a certain `flatMap` that I use at about 20 places. And I am sure it will be 20 more in the future. It is to throw an exception when a `Option` is empty.

Example:

```
def get(serverId: UUID, sessionId: UUID) = authAction.async { implicit request =>
  val user = request.user.get
  serverService.findByIdAndUserId(serverId, user.id.get) flatMap { s =>
    if (s.isEmpty) {
      Future.failed(new NotFoundException)
    } else {
      Future.successful(s.get)
    }
  } flatMap { _ =>
    serverSessionService.findByIdAndServerId(sessionId, serverId)
  } flatMap { s =>
    if (s.isEmpty) {
      Future.failed(new NotFoundException)
    } else {
      Future.successful(s.get)
    }
  } map { s =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(s))
  }
}
```

I am doing the `flatMap` for `Option` checking twice in one controller method...

How can I isolate this part:

```
flatMap { s =>
  if (s.isEmpty) {
    Future.failed(new NotFoundException)
  } else {
    Future.successful(s.get)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using implicit class:

```
implicit class OptionFuture[T](f: Future[Option[T]]) {
  def optionFuture(t: Throwable): Future[T] =
    f.flatMap{
      case Some(x) => Future.successful(x)
      case _ => Future.failed(t)
    }
}

Future{ Some(1) }.optionFuture(new Exception("failed"))
// Success(1)

Future{ None }.optionFuture(new Exception("failed"))
// Failure(java.lang.Exception: failed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to add implicit class to fail if empty:

```
implicit class FutureFailer[T <: Option[_]](f: Future[T]) {
    def failIfEmpty = {
        f.flatMap {
            case None => Future.failed(new NotFoundException)
            case k => Future.successful(k)
        }
    }
}

Future.successful(Option.empty[String]).failIfEmpty.
    flatMap(_ => Future.successful(Option.empty[String])).failIfEmpty
```